# How can I order by 'votes' in CakePHP?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP for a CMS/web service to power an iPhone app.  I'm wondering how I would go about ordering my .find() method so that I can order by the "count" of some external models?

For example:
A **video** object is associated with **votes**.  So there are multiple Vote rows (with user_id and video_id) for a single Video row.

```
$videos = $this->Video->find('list', array( <<orderby stuff>> ));
```

How can I change the orderby clause so that it returns the 25 most popular videos by **votes**?

Comment: Do you basically need a COUNT(*) on the votes table?

Comment: Can you post the relationship between the tables. i.e. I assume that a video hasMany votes and a vote belongsTo a video.

Comment: @Belinda absolutely.  Vote belongsTo Video, Video hasMany Vote.

Comment: Have you considered using a [counter cache](http://book.cakephp.org/view/816/counterCache-Cache-your-count)?

Comment: I think my comment below will cover both options for retrieving the data you are looking for. If you need the name and id of the video or the id only. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `videos` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `votes` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `video_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

The SQL you are trying to write is something like:

```
    SELECT 
      count(id), 
      video_id 
   FROM votes 
   GROUP BY video_id 
   ORDER BY count(id) DESC 
   LIMIT 25;
```

The problem is, it will not return the video name. This is easily remedied with a JOIN or by using cakes recursive feature. Given the above, I would write the following:

```
$this->Vote->recursive = 1;
$vote_info = $this->Vote->find('all', 
   array(
      'fields' => array('count(Vote.id)','Video.name'), 
      'group' => array('video_id'), 
      'order' => array('count(Vote.id) DESC'), 
      'limit' => 25, 
   )
);
```

When you get the data back, you will also get the Video information (due to the recursive option being set to 1) as long as your relationships in the models are set up correctly.

For example, the data will look something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [count(`Vote`.`id`)] => 3
                )
            [Video] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Dumb and Dumber
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [count(`Vote`.`id`)] => 1
                )
            [Video] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Lord of the Rings
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [count(`Vote`.`id`)] => 1
                )
            [Video] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Just Do It
                )
        )
)
```

I think you can see from here how to access the data in your view.

Hoppy Coding!

UPDATE:
If you only need the video id, you can do something like:

```
$this->Vote->recursive = 0;
$votes = $this->Vote->find('all', 
   array(
      'fields' => array('count(Vote.id) as count', 'Vote.video_id'), 
      'order' => array('count(Vote.id) DESC'),
      'group' => array('Vote.video_id'),
      'limit' => 25,
   )
);
```

This will return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 3
                )
            [Vote] => Array
                (
                    [video_id] => 4dac4de7-4f80-48c1-8a02-83b4dfa458e5
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                )
            [Vote] => Array
                (
                    [video_id] => 4dac4ddc-712c-4795-8d9a-83b4dfa458e5
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                )
            [Vote] => Array
                (
                    [video_id] => 4dac4df0-382c-4bb5-a5ee-83b4dfa458e5
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: isn't easier to use just a plain SQL? xD

Comment: You are not limited by the CakePHP framework. You can for sure write a custom join query that will mimic the same results. That is effective as well. However, the question was how to use the .find function to get the results. This is how to do that. If the question was worded differently, I would have provided that solution instead.

Comment: Keep in mind @yes123, it's not always about what is easiest, but about what is right. ;)

Comment: The only problem with this is that if a Video has no Votes... how can I get the query to include those too?   (essentially left join)

Answer (score 1):

Dunhamzzz's comment of using a [counterCache](http://book.cakephp.org/view/816/counterCache-Cache-your-count) ( +1 ) is the best approach. After you have set this up everytime someone adds a vote a field called vote_count will be incremented in the video table for the associated video. You can then simply sort by this field.

So in your Vote Model

```
var $belongsTo = array('Video' => array('counterCache' =>true));
```

And create the vote_count field in your Video table

Then sort

```
$videos = $this->Video->find('list', array( 'order' => array('vote_count DESC'), 'limit'=>25 ))
```

Comment: Your query produces an error `SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'vote_count' in 'order clause'` since the vote count is a `count()` of the votes from another table.

Comment: No it does not, read the article on counterCache mentioned in my answer

Comment: Yes it would. Keep in mind I am not arguing that your solution is a bad implementation. But the question being asked is "how can I order by count of an external model". Not, "how should I change my schema and code to implement counterCache". The OP indicates there is no counter column in the video table. Your solution requires a new column to be added to the `video` table. So based on the existing schema, and the question being asked, the SQL error will occur when trying to use the counterCache unless there is a modification to the schema. It is a technicality I know.

Comment: Yes I stated add a video_count field,so an error wouldn't arise from following my answer.

Comment: Do you really think every question on here should be read pedantically regardless of whether the OP knows what maybe the best practice is?

Following the example you have offered with the 'count()' and 'order by' what do you think the performance hit result will be on a db of 10,000 videos each with 5000 votes???

Comment: @Leo: In a properly designed database in a real database engine? Not terribly significant. Columns like `vote_count` should be avoided if at all possible.

Comment: @Leo: This is simply wrong. You should never store anything you can calculate. What happens if something unforseen causes `vote_count` not to be updated? It becomes instantly (and permanently) invalid. -1

Comment: @Ken: so the counterCache behaviour built into Rails ( and therefore CakePHP ) is invalid then? If I'm wrong I'll accept it but there must be a lot of people using this behaviour that they read in the documentation of these frameworks? I don't see a flurry of negative comments on other counterCache suggestions on SO either>